# HTTP Error 426 when I am calling my application

Tags: node.js, http, localhost, ip

I am running a vote application with node.js and it's running on `localhost:3500`.
When I try to call it with another PC with the IP-Address it give me 
`HTTP ERROR 426`

Comment: Can you post some of your sample code?

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected result.

`localhost` is the hostname that means *this computer*. It is a convenient way to host a server on your machine *as if* it was a remote server, but the reality is that it is only accessible to your machine, and that is why you can't access services running on *your* `localhost:3500` from *another machine*.